# How to search when joining 3 tables but exclude result for one of them?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, outer-join

I've been tying for hours now to get a particular result and haven't found any answer on the web - and as I'm not an SQL expert at *all*, I'm asking a question here.

I have 3 tables: `user` (`id`, `name`...), `cars` (`id`, `type`, `color`, `engine power`...) and an intermediary table to save all the scores users gave to the car: `scores` (`id`, `user_id`, `car_id`, `score`).

I'm trying to find a query that could return for one particular user, all the cars that **he hasn't rated yet**. I've tried the following but it returns null:

```
$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cars LEFT OUTER JOIN scores ON cars.id = scores.car_id WHERE scores.user_id != ('".$userId."')");
```

Does someone have a clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  cars
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM scores WHERE car_id = cars.id AND user_id = ?)
```

where `?` is the ID of that particular user.

A composite index in `scores` over `(car_id, user_id)` is useful here.

Comment: Wow, it works perfect, thanks a milion! I'll check out the composite index you talked about, never used that before...

Answer (score 2):

You can use your code with small modification:

```
SELECT * FROM cars 
LEFT OUTER JOIN scores ON cars.id = scores.car_id and scores.user_id=".$userId."
WHERE scores.id IS NULL
```

Comment: +1 That's the alternative. IMHO not as expressive as NOT EXISTS, though.

Comment: @Zapadlo Could you explain your comment? What is totally:) incorrect in this query? I think before posting comment like this you should read more about sql and left join:)

Comment: @Zapadlo Agree, I have mixed cars and scores. Edited. Thanks

Comment: @Andrey: You could also use `SELECT cars.* FROM ...` as you don't want the fields from the `scores` table to show. They'll be all NULLs, after all.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM
car c
WHERE c.id NOT IN (
    SELECT s.car_id
    FROM score s, user u
    WHERE u.id = s.user_id
        AND u.id = ?
)
```

Comment: Do you really need the `user` table?